# set the evil shift width to the buffer-local indentation in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, evil-mode

I use evil, which got

```
(defcustom evil-shift-width 4
  "The offset used by \\<evil-normal-state-map>\\[evil-shift-right] \
and \\[evil-shift-left]."
  :type 'integer
  :group 'evil)
```

I'd like to set evil-shift-width to the buffer-local indent width (the variable `indent`).

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
      (function (lambda ()
                  (setq evil-shift-width indent))))
```

What did I miss?

Comment: You are missing a pair of parentheses around the `(setq ...)` form and a clarification on what you want or expect `indent` to be.

Comment: @tripleee hope it helps.

Comment: What happens and what do you expect to happen? Where does `indent` come from and when is it set?

Comment: `indent` should come from the current major mode and represent the indent width, 4 for python and 2 for ruby and so on. Currently, I have it at 2 for ruby, but that's annoying for python.

Comment: Have you tried with a minimal .emacs?  Is the problem in python mode?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without more information, I believe I understand the problem to be that desire is for `evil-shift-width` to be set to 4 in `python-mode` and 2 in `ruby-mode` (for two examples), yet it is always set to 2.

The problem in this case comes from the fact that `indent` isn't defined globally in Emacs, and certainly not in `python-mode`.  In `python-mode` there is a variable `python-indent`, which is set to 4, and that is the variable to use.

While annoying to have to use custom variables for each of the major modes, that's what each of the modes actually use, and that's probably the solution that will actually work:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (function (lambda ()
          (setq evil-shift-width python-indent))))
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
  (function (lambda ()
          (setq evil-shift-width ruby-indent-level))))
```

Adding a new one for each major-mode you want supported.